# Is authorizating add-ons in this way secure?

Tags: authentication, web-application, browser-extensions

I have a website, for which I made accompanying add-on to Firefox and Chrome. Both of those are distributed privately. In Firefox they can be installed only from my website, and for Chrome the link to store can only be obtained on the site as well.

The add-on is currently authorized in the following manner:

- User logs into the website
- User goes to settings
- User chooses 'New Key'
- The key is revealed in text field, where users can copy it, after that the key will never be shown again, unless new one is generated
- The user must copy and paste the key to addon
- The add-on is sending the key as part of the communication with the server.

The server uses the key to authorize add-on as one of the users. It gives the add-on permission of the authorized user, however some permissions reduced due to password-less authorization, for example the user can not change password or generate new application key (This can be only done on the website where user must log-in with login and password).

All users are warned about possible severe effects of sharing the keys with other people.

The website uses HTTPS with HSTS and was recently submitted into preloading list. Therefore I am not concerned about HTTP leak of the key. The key is stored as part of browser.storage API

I am however concerned if the keys are good enough for the applications.
Currently the keys are generated using `bin2hex(random_bytes(64))` under PHP.

While the keys have by default limited access to the account, I wonder if this approach is even secure by design, or if there is a better approach, for which I could authorize the add-on, without the users requiring to log-in every time.

By default the key is never automatically deleted, however users are allowed to delete current key, and generating new key removes previous one from the database.

I wonder if there are any possible attacks which I have not thought of, or if there are even better ways to authorize users.

Comment: You could use something like [OAuth2](http://www.bubblecode.net/en/2016/01/22/understanding-oauth2/).  Reinventing the wheel when it comes to security should usually be avoided when possible.

Comment: So this is basically just like an app-specific password?